# Problema na passagem de valor por URL

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar uma forma mais dinâmica de carregar as páginas que estou utilizando, carregando arquivos como CSS apenas em uma página, e dessa página, chamar as outras. Porém, não consigo receber o valor que estou passando pela URL. Segue o código do envio:

```
<div id='navbar' class='navbar-collapse collapse'>
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
    <li class='dropdown'>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='0false'>Ofícios<span class='caret'></span></a>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
            <li class='dropdown'>
                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>Funcionário<span class='caret'></span></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><a href='funcionario_cadastrar.php?link=17'>Cadastrar</a></li>                      
                    <li><a href='funcionario_listar.php?link=18'>Listar</a></li>
                    <li><a href='funcionario_consultar.php?link=19'>Consultar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

E do recebimento:

```
$link = $_GET["link"];
print_r($_GET["link"]);
if(isset($_GET["link"])){
    /*
    $pagina[17] = "funcionario_cadastrar.php";
    $pagina[18] = "funcionario_listar.php";
    $pagina[19] = "funcionario_consultar.php";

    if(!empty($link)){
        if(file_exists($pagina[$link])){
            include $pagina[$link];
        }else{
            include "bem_vindo.php";
        }
    }else{
        include "bem_vindo.php";
    }
}else{
    include "bem_vindo.php";
    */
}
```

Comment: O `isset()` deve ser feito direto no `$_GET`. Na dúvida faça `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Aqui funciona normalmente, seu eu acessar a página que contém o link, ao ser redirecionado ela vai iniciar a variável `$link`, agora seu eu tentar acessar direto a página que pega o link dá um erro, explique melhor o que está fazendo e se possível coloque o código completo  da página com o link, pode ser alguma outra coisa...

Comment: Editei a publicação com o restante do código.

Comment: Aparece alguma coisa do `print_r()`?

Comment: Não, tentei colocar dentro e fora do _if_ para ver se tinha diferença, mas continuou sem mostrando nada.

Comment: vc tem o apache instalado?

Comment: Sim, utilizo o Apache2.

Comment: O código parece funcionar, será que não está enviando para o arquivo errado? Deixa seu arquivo que recebe só assim, veja se aparece algo. `echo (isset($_GET["link"]) ? $_GET["link"] : 'nada');`

Comment: Dessa vez apareceu a mensagem "nada".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id='navbar' class='navbar-collapse collapse'>
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
    <li class='dropdown'>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='0false'>Ofícios<span class='caret'></span></a>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
            <li class='dropdown'>
                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>Funcionário<span class='caret'></span></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><a href='index.php?link=17'>Cadastrar</a></li>                      
                    <li><a href='index.php?link=18'>Listar</a></li>
                    <li><a href='index.php?link=19'>Consultar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

if( isset($_GET["link"])){

  $link = $_GET["link"];
  switch ($link) {
        case 17:
            include="tema17.php";
            break;
        case 18:
            include="tema18.php";
            break;
        case 19:
            include="tema19.php";
            break;
        default:
            include="temaDefault.php";
            break;
    }
}
```

É isso que eu faço para incluir arquivos conforme o valor da variável, redireciona para a mesma página que no seu caso pode ser um index.php e dentro dele você coloca esse código e assim você inclui quantos você quiser.

Com isso você cria um único menu, cabeçalho e rodapé.

Comment: Tá dando o erro: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: link na linha `switch ($link) {
 case 18:
  include "funcionario_listar.php";
  break;    
 }`

Comment: Você tem que declarar ela com algum valor antes, o seu $_GET["link"] pode preencher esta variável $link e só com isso adicionar os arquivos como você quer fazer.

Comment: Acabei de editar meu exemplo, segue que pode dar certo.

Answer (score 1):

Tente dessa forma. Fiz uns testes e funcionou.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["link"]) && $_GET["link"] != '') {
    $link = $_GET["link"];

    switch ($link) {
        case 17:
            echo "funcionario_cadastrar.php"; //include "funcionario_cadastrar.php";
        break;
        case 18:
            echo "funcionario_listar.php"; //include "funcionario_listar.php";
        break;
        case 19:
            echo "funcionario_consultar.php"; //include "funcionario_consultar.php";
        break;
        default:
            echo "index.php"; //include "index.php";
        break;
    }
} else {
    echo "index.php"; //include "index.php";
}
```